# Owl Carousel display issue

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am trying to make pictures be in a carousel horizontally, however whenever I try, it displays it weird like it is vertical. Here is a snippet of my code

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="link">
      <img class="gameimg" src="default-placeholder.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      700: {
        items: 6,
      },
      1000: {
        items: 9,
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

[Picture of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiQ0o.png)

I attempted to try to change the height, hoping that would maybe solve it however it didn't do anything but resize the container it was in.

Comment: Please provide a minimal and reproducible example code:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @konekoya Thank you for the comment, that is all the code I used to reproduce this issue I have no idea what is causing it since i have used it before without any issues

Comment: The semi-colon not needed (its on two lines of code)   
...owl-theme'>;  
...</div>;

Comment: @granite Yes sorry I didn't realize I still had those in there either way it wouldn't affect anything but thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not including Owl Carousel's stylesheets in your HTML, you can see the installation guide on their [docs](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html):

Here is the working code after adding these stylesheets:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="link">
          <img class="gameimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1,
          },
          700: {
            items: 6,
          },
          1000: {
            items: 9,
          },
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this I have been stumped on this for a while I must've missed that part!